# export subprocess output result in dictionary or list

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to get the output of the following subprocess call into a dict or in a list. Then, I am going to extract some data from there.

```
arg_list = []
action ="QuotaInfo"
arg_list.append(upnp_path)
arg_list.append(' --action=')
arg_list.append(action)
arg_list.append(' --ip=')
arg_list.append('10.10.8.89')


# x = Popen(arg_list, shell=True)

output = list()

y = subprocess.call(["python", arg_list])
```

**The output**

```
***************Retrieving the QUOTA info for : 10.10.8.89 ***************
INFO::root:Trying main server 10.10.8.40:9000::224
DEBUG::root:Cookies: 'TWISTED_SESSION=988fedac2b7f62cc280c6865f74d9600'::107
containerId  :  3
title  :  pvr
quotaInfoName  :  user
quotaInfoUsedsize  :  17767158
containerRestricted  :  0
quotaInfoMaxsize  :  239221162
class  :  object.container
containerParentid  :  0
INFO::root:Trying main server 10.10.8.40:9000::224
DEBUG::root:Cookies: 'TWISTED_SESSION=988fedac2b7f62cc280c6865f74d9600'::107
```

How I can achieve that ? Thanks

Comment: what's your error? you should look into `subprocess.Popen` if you want the output.

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrançoisFabre I want to save that output in dict or list. I can get that output on the cmd screen. My question is how can I pass that data into a dict or a list ?

Comment: dict of what? what would be the keys & the values?

Comment: I need to take "quotaInfoUsedsize  :  17767158" and "quotaInfoMaxsize  :  239221162" from the output. when you use call method, that does not allow you to save the data in the string, dict or list, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer by myself.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT



 p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  output = p.stdout.read()

  print output
```

Comment: I would omit `stdin=PIPE` since you don't have anything to pipe to. and don't forget `p.wait()` to wait & get command return code

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks a lot for your help Jean.